# Can you deploy a flask app with FileZilla?

Tags: python, flask, filezilla

I am making my first Flask app. I tried deploying with FileZilla but FileZilla runs index.html before it runs index.py. Am I suppose to use a different software to host it or should change the way my files are organized?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: FileZilla is an ftp client. It doesn't host the files. Where are you using FileZilla to upload to?

Comment: `FileZilla` is an `FTP` client, it is not a `web server`. It can't be used to ''run"' html nor python.

Comment: Before, I would connect to the server and in a directory, put my html, css, and js files. When I go to the appropriate website, I would see my website.

Comment: Is there any other free softwares I can use instead?

Comment: You need a webserver that can run python.

Comment: Flask is a web server... You need Putty or SSH software to start a terminal on a remote server to run your Flask code

Comment: Flask can been run using python and accessed via localhost: see this tutorial: http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/python-flask-windows-development-environment-setup/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most traditional shared web hosts will not be set up for Python web applications. It can be done (for example, FCGI is an option, or even plain ol' CGI technically) but you would need to talk to your web hosting provider to figure out what tools they offer.

If they do offer FCGI, http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/fastcgi/ has some instructions on how to set it up using Flup. It's also possible (but a long shot) that they support mod_wsgi or similar, in which case you could use that.